# How can I return the odd numbers of a list, using only recursion in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I do not want to use while or for loops, just want to use recursion to return the odd numbers in a given list. Thanks!

Comment: @user481083: Ah! you should always say so.

Comment: @user481083: Deleting my answer as you wanted recursion and the answer is provided by GWW. I am not sure, why i got upvoted for my answer. +1 to GWW

Comment: -1 @ zero-effort "do my homework for me so I can avoid the inconvenience of learning anything"

Comment: @GlennMaynard sorry it came off as hw, as of 1 year ago [when this question was asked] I was in school studying a totally unrelated subject (finance)! I labaled it hw, because it was akin to questions asked in the hw section. Sorry it bothered you though..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def find_odds(numbers):
  if not numbers:
    return []
  if numbers[0] % 2 == 1:
    return [numbers[0]] + find_odds(numbers[1:])
  return find_odds(numbers[1:])
```

No extra variables or parameters needed.

Comment: This is (IMNSHO) the best solution to date since it both minimises the arguments passed and doesn't damage the original list. +1.

Comment: @pax, I have a dumb question to ask...isn't a new list being created everytime `[numbers[0]] + find_odds(numbers[1:])` is executed? :-\ @Josh, +1

Comment: @st0le, that line actually creates two lists, one with the first element, and one with all the remaining elements.

Comment: Can someone please explain in a little bit more detail how this program works? Btw when the list is too long then the program starts to spit out `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that is a risk of using recursion. What parts of the code snippet would you like clarified?

Comment: @JoshMatthews I'm confused on what the second if statement is doing. How is it going through the list and checking off which ones are even or odd? Then finally returning only the odd ones.

Comment: @Alex After the initial empty check, find_odds checks if the first element in the list is odd. If it is, it returns a list made of the first element concatenated with the result of calling find_odds on the rest of the elements in the list. Otherwise, if the first element is not odd, it returns the result of calling find_odds on the rest of the elements in the list, ignoring the first element. In this way, all of the elements in the list will be processed one at a time, and the resulting list will only contain the odd elements that were encountered.

Answer (score 7):

```
def only_odd(L):
    return L[0:L[0]&1]+only_odd(L[1:]) if L else L
```

This version is much faster as it avoids making copies of L

```
def only_odd_no_copy(L, i=0):
    return L[i:i+(L[i]&1)]+only_odd_no_copy(L, i+1) if i<len(L) else []
```

This one only uses O(log n) stack space

```
def only_odd_logn(L):
    x=len(L)/2+1
    return L[:L[0]&1] + only_odd2(L[1:x]) + only_odd_logn(L[x:]) if L else L
```

Comment: @dcolish: `some_int & 1` is just an obfuscated version of `some_int % 2` ... what's to like? It's the L[0:boolean] that's the stroke of gnenius ... +1 from me.

Comment: Hmm...i must have put that zero there because explicit is better than implicit

Comment: @gnibbler, You must have, but I went ahead and removed it while I was profiling your code. +1  I think you had the best answer before mine ;)

Comment: @John, whats not too like. Bitwise ops are awesome and I don't think we see them used enough. Yes that other bit is quite clever too.

Comment: @gnibbler: ... `if L[i:] else ...` does make a copy of (on average) about half of L, and immediately throws it away. How about a PEP for a composite IS_SLICE_EMPTY or SLICE_LEN opcode :-?

Comment: @John, You are correct. let me replace it with `i<len(L)`

Answer (score 3):

```
def find_odds(numbers, odds):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return
    v = numbers.pop()
    if v % 2 == 1:
        odds.append(v)
    find_odds(numbers, odds)

odds = []
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
find_odds(numbers,odds)
# Now odds has the odd numbers
print odds
```

Here's a test output of what I get when I run this

[7, 5, 3, 1]

Comment: where is the odds list returned?

Comment: The variable odds I edited my answer to help a bit

Comment: It is modified by [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) .  So you'd call the function like ``result = []; find_odds(nums, result)``

Comment: i tried this out and it is not working for me

Comment: Please don't do the homework for someone next time.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the default stack depth limit of 1000 in python, I would really not use recursion for this. I know there are a lot of recursive implementations above so here's a non-recursive one that is doing it the python way:

```
print filter(lambda x: x % 2, range(0, 10))
```

And for the sake of completeness; if you really really must use recursion here's my go at it. This is very similar to the version by Josh Matthews.

```
def rec_foo(list):
    if not list:
        return []
    return ([list[0]] if list[0] % 2 else []) + rec_foo(list[1:])

print rec_foo(range(1, 10))
```

Comment: +1: filter seems to be the pythonic way.

Comment: A more-pythonic way would be `[x for x in lst if x % 2]`. And please don't use builtin names (list) as parameter names.

Comment: Well, I'll admit the use of list wasnt the best choice, but hey we all make mistakes. What I'll never understand is how a list comp is more pythonic than a builtin function.

Comment: Sort of declared that comprehensions are a "better" way in this: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: I've always been one for testing his benevolence.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it which returns the list of odd numbers rather than modifying the list passed in. Very similar to that provided by `GWW` but I thought I'd add it for completeness.

```
def find_odds(numbers, odds):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return odds

    if numbers[0] % 2 == 1:
        odds.append(numbers[0])

    return find_odds(numbers[1:],odds)

print find_odds([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[])
```

Output is:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: can you think of a way to do it with only one parameter? thank you

Comment: Sure, you could (as one way) create the list to contain _all_ the information and just pass the list. But that's an even worse requirement than your equally arbitrary "must use recursion" one, since it was added after the question was answered. And, to be honest, I'd rather help people out than play "let's change the requirements" games - it's not as if I don't get enough of that in my _real_ job :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a party, I just thought I'd chime in with a nice, sensible, Real Programmer<sup>TM</sup> solution. It's written in emacs and inspired by gnibbler's answer. Like his, it uses `&1` instead of `% 2` (adding 2 into `co_consts` is pure decadence if 1 is already there) and uses that nifty trick for getting the first element only if it's odd, but shaves some cycles off for a time savings of around 5% (on my machine, running 2.6.5 compiled with GCC 4.4.3 on a linux2 kernel).

```
from opcode import opmap
import types

opcodes = [opmap['LOAD_FAST'],      0,0,   #    L
           opmap['JUMP_IF_FALSE'],  24,0, 
           opmap['DUP_TOP'],
           opmap['LOAD_CONST'],     0,0,   #    0
           opmap['BINARY_SUBSCR'],  
           opmap['LOAD_CONST'],     1,0,   #    1
           opmap['BINARY_AND'],
           opmap['SLICE+2'],
           opmap['LOAD_GLOBAL'],    0,0,   #    odds
           opmap['LOAD_FAST'],      0,0,
           opmap['LOAD_CONST'],     1,0,
           opmap['SLICE+1'],
           opmap['CALL_FUNCTION'],  1,0,
           opmap['BINARY_ADD'],
           opmap['RETURN_VALUE']]

code_str = ''.join(chr(byte) for byte in opcodes)

code = types.CodeType(1, 1, 4, 0x1 | 0x2 | 0x40, code_str, (0, 1),
                      ('odds',), ('L',), '<nowhere>', 'odds',
                      0, '')

odds = types.FunctionType(code, globals())
```

Comment: +1, Would love to see the outcome of the OP submitting this for their homework. I added a couple of improved options to my answer

Comment: +1 for the wtf look of the prof

Answer (score 1):

```
odds = []
def findOdds(listOfNumbers):
    if listOfNumbers[0] % 2 == 1:
        odds.append(listOfNumbers[0])
    if len(listOfNumbers) > 1:
        findOdds(listOfNumbers[1:])

findOdds(range(0,10))
print odds
# returns [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Comment: This is clearly a superior solution to recursion.

Comment: So, when your customer asks you for a web app to run under IIS (a very specific requirement), what do you think they will say when you deliver a Websphere version because it's "clearly a superior solution"? :-)

Comment: In this situation, I would berate the teacher for asking a stupid question. :)  It always was a favorite past-time of mine.

Comment: @paxdiablo - different scenario

Comment: @Scott: I take it you don't work out, then.

Comment: -1 for the incorrect regex-based solution. Not only does it not use recursion, but it doesn't come close to working (it returns `1` if you pass it `12`)! If you want to do it with just a single expression, `filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, arrayOfNumbers)` is the proper way to do it, not regexes.

Comment: @Gabe, you don't even need the == 1

Comment: @Scott A regex for numbers (which means str->int->str conversion) does sound like a hammer-nail situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def fodds(alist, odds=None):
...     if odds is None: odds = []
...     if not alist: return odds
...     x = alist[0] # doesn't destroy the input sequence
...     if x % 2: odds.append(x)
...     return fodds(alist[1:], odds)
...
>>> fodds(range(10)) # only one arg needs to be supplied
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] # same order as input
>>>
```

This one avoids the list copying overhead, at the cost of getting the answer backwards and a big increase in the ugliness factor:

```
>>> def fo(aseq, pos=None, odds=None):
...     if odds is None: odds = []
...     if pos is None: pos = len(aseq) - 1
...     if pos < 0: return odds
...     x = aseq[pos]
...     if x % 2: odds.append(x)
...     return fo(aseq, pos - 1, odds)
...
>>> fo(range(10))
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def odds(L):
    if L == []: 
        return []
    else:
        if L[0]%2:
            B = odds(L[1:])
            B.append(L[0])
            return B
        else:
            return odds(L[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a bunch of other answers but I think mine's the cleanest:

```
def odds(L):
   if not L: 
      return []
   return [L[0]] * (L[0] % 2) + odds(L[1:])
```

Fun exercise but just to reiterate, don't ever do this recursively in practice.

Comment: mutating the input arg to an empty list is clean?

Answer (score 0):

well since we're all contributing:

```
def odds(aList):
    from operator import lshift as l
    if aList and not aList[1:]:
        return aList if aList[-1] - l(aList[0]>>1, 1) else list()
    return odds(aList[:len(aList)/3+1]) + odds(aList                                     \
    [len(aList)/3+1:]) if aList else []
```